Support for Ultra Wide Displays in 7 and 8
Long-time elementary OS user, my workstation has 3x 1440p via NVIDIA 1080Ti and everything works great with window management. I can split windows on each monitor so I can have 6 split windows across all displays (2 per screen).
I'm considering getting an ultrawide monitor, but I'm wondering whether Gala has any support for dividing view space evenly on wider displays.
I'm also aware that we are getting Wayland in 8. Does anyone have a current eOS 7 install with an ultrawide or know enough about 8 to say whether more advanced window management is on the horizon?
If not, is anyone familiar with tiling window managers and using them instead of Gala?

If you're looking at using an ultrawide monitor with elementary OS, Gala doesn’t currently offer built-in support for splitting the view evenly across wide displays. While it works great for managing multiple monitors (like your 3x 1440p setup), it doesn’t have native tiling or more advanced window management features for ultrawides.
With eOS 8 moving to Wayland, there might be some improvements in window management, but there’s no official word yet on specific ultrawide support or advanced tiling features. Wayland could bring better flexibility and performance, so it’s worth keeping an eye on that.
If you're eager to use more advanced window management now, you could try a tiling window manager like i3, Sway (which works on Wayland), or bspwm. These will give you complete control over window splitting, including on ultrawide displays. That said, you'd likely need to do a bit of customization to integrate these smoothly with elementary OS’s aesthetic.
Another option is KWin from KDE Plasma. It’s a powerful window manager with lots of features and can be run on Wayland, but like with the tiling managers, you'd need to configure it to work with eOS's environment.
Hope that helps!
